# Free shipping by excluding coupon discount

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to give free shipping, when subtotal is greater or equal to 75 and country is United state.

But when the subtotal is 100 and after applying the coupon discount subtotal become less then 75, then user still able to get free shipping.

How I can create a shipping rule, so that user only receive free shipping when sub total greater then or equal to 75 after applying the discount ?

Please suggest me, thanks

Comment: Did you get solution for this? I am also facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the `collectRates` method of `freeshipping`

For this copy `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping.php` in local folder with same directory combination.

and replace this condition ::

```
if (($request->getFreeShipping())
    || ($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >=
        $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal'))
)
```

With

```
if (($request->getFreeShipping())
    || ($request->getPackageValueWithDiscount() >=
        $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal'))
)
```